# NestJS: findManyEntities not including relation table

Tags: node.js, swagger, nestjs, typeorm

My problem is that, I have this `ActivityArticle` entity that is has a `OneToMany` relationship to `ActivityArticleImage` but `findManyEntities` is does not include the `ActivityArticleImage`, but when I create a custom method it works.

Here is my service that needs to work:

```
    @Injectable()
export class ActivityArticleService extends TypeOrmCrudService<ActivityArticle> {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(ActivityArticle)
    private activityArticleRepository: Repository<ActivityArticle>,
  ) {
    super(activityArticleRepository);
  }

  async findManyEntities(options: FindOptions<ActivityArticle>) {
    return this.activityArticleRepository.find({
      relations: ['articleImage'],
      where: options.where,
    });
  }

  async getArticlesWithImage() {
    return await this.activityArticleRepository.find({
      relations: ['articleImage'],
    });
  }
}
```

Controller code:

```
@Controller({
  path: 'activity-article',
  version: '1',
})
export class ActivityArticleController
  implements CrudController<ActivityArticle>
{
  constructor(public service: ActivityArticleService) {}

  get base(): CrudController<ActivityArticle> {
    return this;
  }

  @ApiOperation({ summary: 'Get articles with image.' })
  @Get('article-with-image')
  @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
  public async getArticlesWithImage() {
    return this.service.getArticlesWithImage();
  }
}
```

Sample output for `findManyEntities`

[image]

Sample output for `getArticlesWithImage`

[image]

How can I possibly work for `findManyEntities` because I need its this functionality that `getArticlesWithImage` doesnt have

[image]

Edit:

FindOptions code:

```
    import { EntityCondition } from './entity-condition.type';

export type FindOptions<T> = {
  where: EntityCondition<T>;
};
```

Activity Article Entity:

```
    @Entity()
export class ActivityArticle extends EntityHelper {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;
/*other fields here*/

  @OneToMany(() => ActivityArticleImage, (articleImg) => articleImg.article)
  articleImage: ActivityArticleImage[];
}
```

Acitivity-Article-Image entity:

```
@Entity()
export class ActivityArticleImage extends EntityHelper {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;
/*other fields here*/
  
@ManyToOne(() => ActivityArticle, (article) => article.articleImage)
  article: ActivityArticle;
}
```

Comment: Where is the `FindOptions` interface from?

Comment: @AntoineViscardi, Hi Sir I updated may post. thanks

Comment: Could you include the code for the `ActivityArticle` entity?

Comment: @Gpack, Hi Sir, added activityarticle and image entity. thanks

Comment: When you call `findManyEntities`, resulting in the first sample output you included, what is the value of `options.where`? Could you maybe rerun you experiment and log its value?